# Finding a standard basis for vectors in $P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S$ be the standard basis for $P_2$. Find a basis for the subspace of $P_2$ spanned by
>   $$(-1+x-2x^2),\ (3+3x+6x^2),\  9
> $$

---

I understand that I will have to remove one of the two polynomial vectors to create a linearly independent set, but is that it? I'm not quite sure how to proceed with the problem, am I just overthinking it?

Comment: Are all the signs of your vectors correct (in particular make sure the signs of the coefficients on the $x$'s are correct)?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes I copied the question word for word.

Comment: Then those three vectors already form a basis.

Comment: Oh, ok. I really feel silly now haha. Thank you @Bye_World

Comment: Did you think that $\dim P_n=n$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think so. I thought I had to find a basis for all of $P_2$ including those vectors or something.

Comment: To make you question "self-contained", what is $S$ and what is $P_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $S=\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $P_2$ means the set of real polynomials of order at most $2$.

> "I'm not quite sure how to proceed with the problem"

How about trying [simpler related questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It):

- Do you know what "linear independence" means in $P_2$?
- Can you test if your set of vectors
  $$Q=\{-1+x-2x^2, \ 3+3x+6x^2, \  9\}$$
  is independent or not?
- Let $V$ be the space spanned by $Q$. Do you know what it means by a basis of $V$?